# Extrapolation Handler and NIntegrate: Bug?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I have an list of data which I interpolate such that it returns the value 0 in case I give it values outside of its domain:

```
g = Interpolation[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 1, 4}}], 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
```

Which works fine:

`g[0]` and `g[100]` both return `0`

However, if I want to integrate this function, I get an error message:

`NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 100}]`

> InterpolatingFunction::dmvali: The integration endpoint 0 in dimension
>   1 lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.
>   Extrapolation will be used. InterpolatingFunction::dmvali: The
>   integration endpoint 100 in dimension 1 lies outside the range of data
>   in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

and the output is some large (incorrect) number.

Is this a bug?

Comment: The behavior is certainly incorrect, but recall that `"ExtrapolationHandler"` is *undocumented* functionality, so this will make Support less likely to look at it. As a workaround, just multiply your `InterpolatingFunction[]` with a `Boole[]` factor: `Integrate[Boole[Between[x, First[g["Domain"]]]] g[x], {x, 0, 100}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if it is a bug, or by design `NIntegrate` does not support these options or does not "look" for them.

Notice they are shown in red color as well. Which means they are not officially known

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you could always do it explicitly

```
g = Interpolation[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 1, 4}}]];

With[{left = g["Domain"][[1, 1]], right = g["Domain"][[1, 2]]},
 NIntegrate[If[left <= x <= right, g[x], 0], {x, 1, 100}]
 ]

(*8.33333*)
```

Compare to

```
 NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 1, 5}] // N
 (*8.33333*)
```

And compare to

```
NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 1, 100}] // N
(*3.9804774791666664*^7*)
```